# Is it possible to overload a function at runtime?

Tags: c++, overloading

I'd like to streamline a code that has about a hundred of expressions like this:

```
if( flag )
    AddData( key, some_number );
else
    AddData( key, error_description );
```

Where AddData is overloaded as

```
bool AddData( int key, double value );
bool AddData( int key, const char * error );
```

I'd like to express the code above like this:

```
AddData( key, flag? some_number : error_description );
```

which, of course, won't compile because the value of the flag is determined at runtime and AddData signature needs to be determined at compile time.

Combining both functions into something like

```
bool AddData( int key, bool flag, double value, const char * error );
```

and resolving which of the parameters to use and which one to ignore would work, but it just doesn't look pretty enough.

Thus the question: is it possible to resolve function overloading at runtime in a more reasonable manner?

Comment: `AddData(key, flag ? some_number : error_description);` looks similar to `AddData(key, flag, some_number, error_description);`...

Comment: Is it important that only one of `someNumber`/`errorDescription` gets evaluated? Also, is the flag a different expression each call?

Comment: You could use function pointers.  Based on the input, dereference the appropriate function pointer.

Comment: Also, is any of that data compile-time constant? Are the `key`s used consecutive?

Comment: @Deduplicator: none of the variables are runtime constant.

Comment: So, flag is different for every block, key too, and both some_number and error_description must be calculated? Is doing so when not needed expensive/disruptive?

Comment: You *could* use a variadic function, but I sure wouldn't recommend it.  Type safety is there for a reason.   `bool AddData(int key, bool flag, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Just define a small helper in the function, and use that:

```
auto AddHelper = [](bool flag, int key, double value, const char* error) {
    return flag ? AddData(key, value) : AddData(key, error);
}
```

If the flag is actually always the same, that's a simple change:

```
auto AddHelper = [flag](int key, double value, const char* error) {
    return flag ? AddData(key, value) : AddData(key, error);
}
```

Depend on the compiler for optimization.

Comment: +1 for the second incantation (I bet `flag` is constant over the lifetime of the parent function). It's short enough and has the right intention.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using polymorphism instead of hundreds of ifs.

Instead of a flag have a polymorphic base class that does the data adding and instead of changing the flag you chose the correct derived class.

The calling code would then simply be:

```
data_adder->add(key, value, error_description);
```

Example base class and derived classes:

```
struct DataAdder {
  virtual void add(int key, double value, const char *error) = 0;
 protected:
  ~DataAdder(){};
};

struct ValueDataAdder : DataAdder {
  void add(int key, double value, const char*) override { AddData(key, value); }
};

struct ErrorDataAdder : DataAdder {
  void add(int key, double, const char* error) override { AddData(key, error); }
};
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WLR1aUivU7GBK9GF)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Given an assumption that none of the symbols in the expression in question can be factored out, the best you'll get is

```
AddData(key, flag, some_number, error_description)
```

If you can factor it such that maybe `flag` applies to multiple calls, then you can start to do better with a structure like

```
Adder<flag>{}
  .AddData(key1, val1, error1)
  .AddData(key2, val2, error2)
  .AddData(...)
  .
  .
```

I.e. a 'fluent' interface that remembers which side of the `if` is being taken every time.